# Using Yammer Feed Embed, by Blue Rooster is there a way to change the color?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, yammer

I have installed Yammer Feed Embed, by Blue Rooster is there a way to change the color of the embedded feed?

Comment: You will have to take this to Blue Rooster.  This is considered off-topic here.

Comment: Ok then using the standard embed function on Yammer, is there a way to change the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yammer doesn't allow you to customize the look & feel of their embed feed. But you can turn off the header via configuration option.

Also that blue background is coming from your network configuration. The same color as your web version, and you can change it inside Network configuration page.

Kindly check the answer at below link.

[How to personalize Yammer embed box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909396/how-to-personalize-yammer-embed-box)